# How to get more contrast on anisotropic chrome material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

I want my chrome object to have more contrast and rays like the photo image. I have used 2 shade mixers. One for the texture of the chrome material, with radial texture, and the other with anisotropic nodes to get the chrome rays.

The problem I'm having is:

1. My material there is only 2 rays as seen in orthographic view, but on the actual image, there is more rays on the chrome photo. I'd like to add more contrast.
2. There's a repeating pattern on the side of my object.

[image]

Comment: is it not a question of lighting and HDRI image? What does it give if you add more lights or use and HDRI?

Comment: I added some lights, and also duplicated the chrome sphere to see how it looks. I had already added a HDRI black and white to get more contrast, but it doesn't look as realistic as a metallic anisotropic object. 

https://ibb.co/209rQzM

Comment: Yeah this has everything to do with your lighting. That chelsea stairs one looks like it's still fairly diffuse. The whole place has white walls. Try an HDRI like [this one](https://polyhaven.com/a/studio_small_06).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems it heavily relies on light sources and anisotropic value.

With two light sources and higher anisotropy I could achieve something somewhat similar to your expectations:
[image]